# User validation loop for binary input is not recognising input

Tags: python-3.x

new to programming, but I'm working on a binary to decimal converter and I'm trying to make sure that the only input is either a '0' or '1' and not alpha, and not empty ''.

I have figured out logic for not empty and not alpha input , but I can't figure out the logic for the last condition - if 1 not in string or 0 not in string. It works if I enter either 1 or zero, but this isn't what i'm looking. I just want to check that there is only 1's or 0's and then proceed with the rest of the program.

I've spent hours on just this today so any help is appreciated. :)

Thanks in advance :)

```
def convert_to_decimal(binary_number):
    print('\n')
    #The binary input to be converted, entered as a string.
    binary = input('Please enter binary numbera: ')
    while binary.isalpha() or binary == '':
        print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.a ")
        binary = input('Please enter numberb: ')
    while binary not in '1' and binary not in '0':
        print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.x ")
        binary = input('Please enter numberc: ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I reworked it a little and its a bit inefficient, but here it is. It is a bit self-explanatory, but basically how it works, is it iterates over the inputString, and checks if each number is a 1 or 0 if not, the continue to ask, otherwise continue.

```
def isBinary(stringNum):
    if len(stringNum) ==0:
        return False
    for chr in stringNum:
        if chr != "0" and chr != "1":
            return False
    return True
def convert_to_decimal():
    print('\n')
    #The binary input to be converted, entered as a string.
    binary = input('Please enter binary number: ')
    while not isBinary(binary):
        binary = input('Please enter binary number: ')
```

The reason yours doesn't work is you say if not in 1 and not in 0, which is wrong. `in` in this case returns True if the WHOLE string is in the target("0"). Since "10" isn't completely in 1 or in 0, it will ask you again, so you can see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, I see how you have broken things up and then iterate over each character. that is exactly what i was trying to do, maybe not in two functions, but still excellent example :)

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be to hard to move it to the same function, also make sure you use only one while loop, as that could be a problem too

Answer (score 0):

I hate myself for finding the answer, but it works :)

```
def convert_to_decimal(binary_number):
    print('\n')
    #The binary input to be converted, entered as a string.
    binary = input('Please enter binary numbera: ')
    while binary.isalpha() or binary == '':
        print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.a ")
        binary = input('Please enter numberb: ')
    while not binary.startswith('0') and not binary.startswith('1'):
        print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.x ")
        binary = input('Please enter numberc: ')
```

Comment: wouldn't this would return 0ab as a binary number?

Comment: The solution only half works, unfortunately I can still input digits other than one or zero.... blah... I need to find a way to iterate over each digit and check it. .... not having fun :)